# Yii2 QueryBuilder union not working

Tags: yii2, union

Here is my code. I want to select results from two columns into one. Thanks.

```
   $messages = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idsender as idotherguy'])
               ->from('messages')
               ->where(['idreceiver' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
               ->all(); 
    $messages2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idreceiver as idotherguy'])
               ->from('messages')
               ->where(['idsender' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
               ->all(); 
    $messages->union($messages2);
```

after advice here I also tried....

```
    $messages = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idsender as idotherguy'])
               ->from('messages')
              ->where(['idreceiver' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

    $messages2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idreceiver '])
               ->from('messages')
              ->where(['idsender' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

    $messages->union($messages2);
    $messages->all();
```

and i get query object

```
      yii\db\Query Object
```

(
    [select] => Array
        (
            [0] => idsender as idotherguy
        )

```
[selectOption] => 
[distinct] => 
[from] => Array
    (
        [0] => messages
    )

[groupBy] => 
[join] => 
[having] => 
[union] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [query] => yii\db\Query Object
                    (
                        [select] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => idreceiver as idotherguy
                            )

                        [selectOption] => 
                        [distinct] => 
                        [from] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => messages
                            )

                        [groupBy] => 
                        [join] => 
                        [having] => 
                        [union] => 
                        [params] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                        [where] => Array
                            (
                                [idsender] => 2
                            )

                        [limit] => 
                        [offset] => 
                        [orderBy] => 
                        [indexBy] => 
                        [emulateExecution] => 
                    )

                [all] => 
            )

    )

[params] => Array
    (
    )

[_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
[where] => Array
    (
        [idreceiver] => 2
    )

[limit] => 
[offset] => 
[orderBy] => 
[indexBy] => 
[emulateExecution] =>
```

)

that is it... I tried also answe bellow and used in select  'idreceiver as idotherguy' ... but the result is the same

Comment: separate queries are working just fine

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid the  alias  in united query , use literal select format and apply all to the result only

```
  $messages = (new \yii\db\Query())
             ->select('idsender as idotherguy')
             ->from('messages')
             ->where(['idreceiver' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]); 

  $messages2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
             ->select('idreceiver')
             ->from('messages')
             ->where(['idsender' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]); 

  $messages->union($messages2);
  $messages->all();
```

for see the result you should

```
 foreach($messages as $key=> $value) {

   echo $value->idotherguy;
 }
```

or if the result is an array

```
  foreach($messages as $key=> $value) {

    echo $value['idotherguy'];
 }
```

try check the ral sql code  this way  (instead of $messages->all();)

```
var_dump( $messages->createCommand()->sql);
```

Comment: I still do not get array with results but yii\db\Query Object

Comment: what do you mean .. ?  .. you have error ?  .. wrong result  .. ?   update your question and show also the code when you get the result of the query a try use it .. please

Comment: yii\db\Query Object
(
    [select] => Array
        (
            [0] => idsender as idotherguy
        )

    [selectOption] => 
    [distinct] => 
    [from] => Array
        (
            [0] => messages
        )

    [groupBy] => 
    [join] => 
    [having] => 
    [union] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [query] => yii\db\Query Object
                        
  ....... and more

Comment: don't post code  in comment ... update you question add he code and format proplerly

Comment: I did, check it out please

Comment: you showed the query object  .. theh you could see the $messages contents  .. i have update the answer  .. hope is useful

Comment: no,  you have syntax error, but it returns nothing anyway.. the array that I get is with   echo ('<pre>');
             print_r ( $messages);
              
             echo ('</pre>');

Comment: sintax error removed .. but are you sure you have a valid result with the query ??' ..

Comment: 100% ... when I run queries separately i get the results .... I was thinking to abandon union and use array_merge

Comment: i have update the answer  with a suggestion for check the real code created by the query  ..

Comment: var_dump result is string(143) "(SELECT `idsender` AS `idotherguy` FROM `messages` WHERE `idreceiver`=:qp0) UNION ( SELECT `idreceiver` FROM `messages` WHERE `idsender`=:qp1 )"

Comment: this is the query build by the code  .. running this query in you sql console  .. what happen ? ... using 2 for :qp0, :qp1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#union, you shouldn't have `all()` in your queries

```
$messages = (new \yii\db\Query())
           ->select(['idsender as idotherguy'])
           ->from('messages')
           ->where(['idreceiver' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]); 
$messages2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
           ->select(['idreceiver as idotherguy'])
           ->from('messages')
           ->where(['idsender' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]); 
$messages->union($messages2);
$messages->all();
```

Comment: this,  as the solution from above gives me  yii\db\Query Object, nor array with results

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code offered here like this and it works now fine....

```
   $messages = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idsender as idotherguy'])
               ->from('messages')
               ->where(['idreceiver' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $messages2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
               ->select(['idreceiver as idotherguy'])
               ->from('messages')
              ->where(['idsender' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $messages = $messages->union($messages2)
                ->all();
```

The result now is array with values as I wanted.
         Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idotherguy] => 3
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [idotherguy] => 11
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [idotherguy] => 10
    )
```

)

Thanks for help boys :)